# Silverlight combobox performance issue

Tags: silverlight, performance

I'm facing a performance issue with a crowded combobox (5000 items). Rendering of the drop down list is really slow (as if it was computing *all* items before showing any).

Do you have any trick to make this dropdown display lazy?

Xaml code:

```
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="200" Height="20">
            <TextBlock>Test Combo </TextBlock>
            <ComboBox x:Name="fooCombo" Margin="5,0,0,0"></ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

code behind:

public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

```
    List<string> li = new List<string>();

    int Max = 5000;
    for (int i = 0; i < Max; ++i)
        li.Add("Item - " + i);

    fooCombo.ItemsSource = li;
}
```

Well, there seems to be [a bug](http://coreclr.wordpress.com/2009/09/26/silverlight-3-listbox-combobox-and-autocompletebox-performance/) in the Combobox UI virtualization, so an autocompletebox should be the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `AutoCompleteBox` instead, adjust the number of characters that need to be entered before a drop down list will be filled to limit how many drop down items are needed at any one time.

Comment: @Vinzz: Not sure if there is a true solution (if this is just a work around) since the requirement to fill a combobox with 100s let alone 1000s of items is a not a very good UI design decision in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

If you want an actual ComboBox (and not an `AutoCompleteBox`) that did this you could replace the `ItemsTemplate` with a `VirtualizingStackPanel`. In your example this would look like:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="fooCombo" Margin="5,0,0,0">
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel></VirtualizingStackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
</ComboBox>
```

As a guide though, I'd probably review your usage scenario to see whether or not a `ComboBox` is the correct control for you - since 5000 items seems like a mighty lot for a drop down list.

By the way, the slowness is expected behavior in Silverlight and not a bug.

Comment: This is the better answer.

Comment: This doesn't work in SL5, be careful! I had it in my SL4 project and it broke after upgrade. http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/715111/silverlight-5-combobox-problem